# Zipeg doesn't start on Mac Os X High Sierra 10.13

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra

I have an issue with Zipeg (latest version) after upgrading the OS X version to 10.13 High Sierra.

The program doesn't start anymore, even after removing it with AppCleaner.

I have already tried to reinstall Zipeg, with no success.

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://apple.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @Paul-R Sorry, I didn't know that site, I use only stackoverflow.

Comment: It used to be called "Ask Different" - you already have some questions and answers there. StackOverflow is for programming questions - please use the correct site for non-programming questions.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution to this issue.

I had JDK 6 installed on my Mac OSX before the upgrade to High-Sierra.

The solution was simple: I have reinstalled the JDK 6, with the following command:

```
brew cask reinstall java6
```

After that, Zipeg works again perfectly also on High-Sierra.